# Calculating the height of react component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reactive-programming

I am building a social networking app like instagram using react-redux in which I am using react-infinite to show the posts. Where at present I am hardcoding the element height which works well if the screen size is constant but I want the app to be responsive ie it should work in mobile view also. How can I calculate the height of the element dynamically and set it in react infinite? Currently, my return method looks like

```
    return (
    <div>
      <Infinite elementHeight={1000}
        useWindowAsScrollContainer
        infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset={200}
        onInfiniteLoad={this.handleInfiniteLoad}
        loadingSpinnerDelegate={this.elementInfiniteLoad()}
        isInfiniteLoading={this.props.isInfiniteLoading}
      >

        {posts}
      </Infinite>
    </div>
);
```

where variable posts contains instances of Post component like `<Post 
 key="1"/>,<Post key="2" />`  and so on depending on number of posts. How can I calculate the post height and feed it to infinite react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS module system to apply style your components.

For Example,

```
//app.js

import style from 'app.css';

Class App extends from Component{
       constructor(props){
            super(props);
        }

        render(){
             return <div className={style. container}>
                    <div class name={style.content}>Content</div>
                  </div>
        }
 }

 //app.CSS

 .container{
       height: 500px;
       width: 1000px;
  }

  .content{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
   }

   @media only screen and 
   (max-width: 500px) { 
       .container {
             height: 300px;
             width: 400px;
        }
   }
```

I hope its helpful for you.

Comment: @ Vasi have a look at the react-infinite and then comment its not the right answer the question is about getting the height of react component dynamically

Answer (score 0):

There is a react-height package I've used for this problem before,
 (https://github.com/nkbt/react-height) it will dynamically give you the height of the component should it or its immediate children change.

Comment: @ Ben is it similar to react-measure https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure .i had tried with react measure but it did not work

Comment: I don't know I haven't used that one.